# Changing the length of an array in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Can anyone help me please to find a solution for this? In fact, I am searching for a formula in excel to change the length of a table. For example a table of 1 column and 20 lines would have a serie of #na value one time that began at the 15th line in another time at 16th or 17 .... and I would like to identify the address of the table with real value in the case of 15th it would be for example `A1:A14` to use this address in a vlookup or any other formula.

I am using `="A1:"&address(match(1,A1:A20),1,1)` but when I use it in a formula it take this as a string or text and not a range I think.

Hope to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: Using indirect()